# Broken animation when using custom DisclosureGroup in a SwiftUI List

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, disclosuregroup

Due to constraints of using the default `DisclosureGroup` in a list, I'm trying to make a custom implementation, but I'm running into an issue with the expansion animation, which only occurs when the custom component is in a `List`. Here is the code:

```swift
struct CustomDisclosureGroup<Label: View, Content: View>: View {
    @State private var isExpanded: Bool = false

    private let label: Label
    private let content: Content

    init(@ViewBuilder label: () -> Label, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.label = label()
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    isExpanded.toggle()
                }
            } label: {
                HStack {
                    label
                    Spacer()
                }
            }

            if isExpanded {
                content
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I put it in a List, as so:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items: [Int] = [0, 1, 2, 3]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                CustomDisclosureGroup {
                    Text(item.formatted())
                } content: {
                    Text("Test text")
                    Text("Test text")
                    Text("Test text")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The animation breaks. Compare it to the default disclosure group animation:

| With Custom Component | Default Disclosure Group |
| --- | --- |
| [image: First Image] | [image: Second Image] |

Assume that I cannot use `DisclosureGroup` (and need to use this custom component) and that I must use `List`. How can I fix this broken animation?

Comment: What is the point of `CustomDisclosureGroup`? That is, what part of it can we *not* change? Can you remove the `VStack(spacing: 0)`, for example?

Comment: The point of CustomDisclosureGroup is that it’s an alternative to DisclosureGroup, since the latter adds additional list cells. You can change it.

Comment: "since the latter adds additional list cells" So the point is to *not* have additional list cells?

Comment: Yes exactly. If we simply want expandable content in a list (to be able to use `.onDelete`, .`onMove`), but we _don't_ want the expanded content itself to be another list element.

That is what I mean when I say that the entire disclosure group should be treated as a single list element.

Answer (score 1):

Animations inside a `List` are very restricted and difficult to control, as you have discovered. The same goes for animations inside a `Form`.

Here is an updated version of your `CustomDisclosureGroup` that performs slightly better than what you originaly had, but not by much.

- The content is shown in an overlay, which allows a bit of animation.
- The flag is not toggled `withAnimation`, because this was causing some uncontrollable movement (including movement of the label). Instead, an `.animation` modifier is applied when revealing the content.
- The list insets are set explicitly, to prevent a small amount of label movement when the flag is toggled. This is probably being caused by the difference between the minimum row height (as defined by `defaultMinListRowHeight`) and the height of the label by itself when the view is collapsed.
- Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to have it expand and collapse gradually, so it happens in jumps.

```swift
struct CustomDisclosureGroup<Label: View, Content: View>: View {
    @State private var isExpanded = false
    @State private var isContentVisible = false

    private let label: Label
    private let content: Content

    init(@ViewBuilder label: () -> Label, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.label = label()
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Button {
                if isExpanded {
                    withAnimation {
                        isContentVisible = false
                    } completion: {
                        isExpanded = false
                    }
                } else {
                    isExpanded = true
                }
            } label: {
                HStack {
                    label
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            if isExpanded {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    content
                }
                .hidden()
                .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                    VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        content
                    }
                    .opacity(isContentVisible ? 1 : 0)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                    .frame(height: isContentVisible ? nil : 0, alignment: .top)
                    .clipped()
                    .animation(.easeInOut, value: isContentVisible)
                }
                .onAppear { isContentVisible = true }
                .onDisappear { isContentVisible = false }
            }
        }
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 12, leading: 20, bottom: 12, trailing: 20))
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

If you want to have more control over the animation, you might be better off building a custom `List` instead. This would probably be easier than finding workarounds for all the limitations of a native `List`.